# Retrieving the value of a global variable outside the dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've created a dataTable. I'm receiving about 13 data from the database. I've also declared a global variable and assigning it's value inside the dataTable in mRender event. But, the problem is I cannot bring it out of that. This is how I've tried:

```
var total_amount = 0;
function year_month(year_month) {
                     jQuery("#table").dataTable({
                        "sAjaxSource": "request-db.php?mode=dataTable&year_month=" + jQuery("#year_month").val(),
                        "bDestroy": true,
                        "bPaginate": false,
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "bFilter": false,
                        "bSort": false,
                        "aoColumnDefs": [
                            {
                                "aTargets": [0],
                                "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                                    total_amount = row[14];
                                    alert(total_amount);
                                    return '<a href="form.php?id=' + row[13] + '" target="_blank" title="' + row[0] + '">' + row[0] + '</a>';
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                }
                alert("total"+total_amount);
            });
```

In the first alert, I'm getting the correct value, but in the second alert I get 0(to which I've initialized). How can I get that outside the dataTable? What should I do?

Comment: Can you share a working demo/Fiddle ? There must be easier way to do so...

Comment: @Rayon I don't know how to add those. I'm new to this..

Comment: You said `I've also declared a global variable and assigning it's value inside the dataTable in mRender event.` but your variable names are different (`total_billable_amount` vs `total_amount`).

Comment: That was the old one, I corrected it. Sorry. This is the current one.